# face_recognition.load_image_file("{}"), what does it mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, face-detection

I'm newbie in python. Now I'm working with python related project. I saw following code while I am searching in google related to project.

```
image = face_recognition.load_image_file("{}")
```

What does `"{}"` do inside `load_image_file()` function? Also, When and where should I use it?

Comment: Right now, it is just a string that contains `{}` it depends on what your framework is doing with it. At the same time, dictionary's are defined with `{}`. Say `a = {}` will create a `dict object`.

Comment: `{}` is also used in string formatting, to define a `set` or a `dict`... so many different meanings depending on the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer, without knowing more of how this method `load_image_file` works.  But here are 2 educated guesses which might be accurate:

1. `{}` would be an empty [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).  Dictionaries are very important and useful in Python and work with key:value pairs.  For instance, the following would be a more useful dictionary than the empty one given:

   - `phone_nums = {'home': '867-5309', 'work': '555-1212'}` would create a dictionary that has 2 keys (`'home'` and `'work'`), which are associated with the 2 phone numbers.  For instance, `phone_nums['home']` would yield `867-5309`.
2. `"{}"` would be a [JSON representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) of an empty "Python dictionary". I put Python dictionary in quotes because a key aspect of the JSON representation is that it can "talk" across different languages.  You can write an object to a JSON structure in Python, then open it up in Javascript, or many other languages.  (I mention Javascript because that is where JSON originally comes from.)

---

But back to your question of what it's doing in that method.  If I were to guess, I'd say that the method:

- Looks for a string that is in a JSON representation.
- Looks for some relevant key name in that representation, such as something like `'filename': 'C:\\Users\\my_file.jpeg'`.

  - If it cannot find the `'filename'` keyword, then it uses a default path.

    - In this case, that's what's happening, and what the author of that snippet of code wanted.  However, s/he couldn't simply pass `null` or an empty string, if indeed there was some requirement of a JSON representation of an object/dictionary.  That's all entirely conjecture, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

```
face_recognition.api.load_image_file(file, mode='RGB')[source]
Loads an image file (.jpg, .png, etc) into a numpy array

Parameters: 
file – image file name or file object to load
mode – format to convert the image to. Only ‘RGB’ (8-bit RGB, 3 channels) and ‘L’ (black and white) are supported.
Returns:    
image contents as numpy array
```

https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html#face_recognition.api.load_image_file

So you need to pas image path or object. `"{}"` sims incomplete code to me.